# Tesseract OCR configurations and image manipulations

Tags: c#, image-processing, tesseract

I've been reading a bunch of posts and stuff on bad outputs from Tesseract .Net wrapper with various image "types", but I couldn't figure out a solution to my bad output.

Here's the picture I'm trying to parse:
[image: Image to parse]

As you can see there are different fonts, sizes, foregrounds and backgrounds. I tried to grayscale it and upscale it by different amounts but nothing comes close to correctly parsing the whole image.

```
TesseractEngine ocr = new TesseractEngine(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "tessdata"), "fra", EngineMode.Default);
ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÉÈ0123456789:'");
Page pg = ocr.Process(image.ToGrayscale().ScaleByPercent(200));
MessageBox.Show(pg.GetText());
```

With this code (let me know if the details of `ToGrayScale()` and `ScaleByPercent(...)` would help), here's the output I get:

> 8300 QÉMQ I09'0'9I
>
> PIOII' :

Which seemingly corresponds to `Bacc. génie logiciel` & `Profil :`.

That being said, I know very little on image transformation so examples or hints would greatly help, but I'm totally willing to dig into linked stuff/documentation if necessary. How should I proceed to process such an image ?

---

**EDIT:** With some manips (suggested by @Yves Daoust) I've managed to reach this point:

[image: NewResults]

However the output (on the right) isn't quite perfect yet. I've been struggling still to provide configs to the Tesseract so that it would only accept words from a certain list. Here's my attempt:

```
var initVars = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
            { "load_system_dawg", false },
            { "user_words_suffix", "fra.user-words" },
            { "language_model_penalty_non_freq_dict_word", 1 },
            { "language_model_penalty_non_dict_word", 1 }
        };
TesseractEngine ocr = new TesseractEngine(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "tessdata"), "fra", EngineMode.Default, 
            Enumerable.Empty<string>(), initVars, false);
```

I've been looking for examples on how to provide such configs but I've only found short, undetailed textual explanations.

Comment: Please read https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality Especially binarization part

Comment: Yes I had already began some of the stuff mentionned there (will most likely edit OP later to provide more info on various tests). I had read "This is converting an image to black and white. Tesseract does this internally, but the result can be suboptimal, particularly if the page background is of uneven darkness." for the binarization and thought it was done automatically, isn't that correct ?

Answer (score 3):

You can help Tesseract to a great extent by extracting the characters yourself, which is pretty trivial here: retain only the pixels in white (and in other colors for other parts of the form).

---

By the way, the characters are so predictable that you could do the recognition yourself (by simple pixel-wise comparison), without the help of Tesseract.

Comment: Wow a simple answer but a logical one ! I will try that and see how it goes. I thought pixel-wise was a super slow approach but maybe I'll give it a shot too (performance is actually important but not crucial)

Comment: @Mat: to access pixels from C#, make sure to use the LockBits/UnlockBits mecanism, rather than GetPixel/SetPixel. The difference in performance is huge.

Comment: I've managed to extract single colors so far but the results are about 50-60% accurate with that method. I will try to add more to it and edit the OP later.

Comment: @Mat: are the resulting images clean around the characters ?

Comment: @Mat: you should train Tesseract with that particular font. As I already said, you can also do without Tesseract. The characters are touching, but you know their size, so splitting should't be an issue.

Comment: Like I said in my edit, I havent found examples of such trainings and I'm not a pro; I totally get the idea, but I don't know how to do it. As for not using Tesseract, I'll do that only if I absolutely don't manage to get the results I'm looking for since I'd really like to have a better understanding of OCR.